# How to write an elisp function returning the contents of a file as a string?

Tags: file, elisp

Well, the title has it all;).  Of course, I can create a new buffer, `insert-file-contents` into it, then put it into a variable, kill the buffer and return the variable - but this seems an overkill.  Is there a better way?

NB. My use case is an `.emacs` declaration of `smtpmail-auth-credentials` - I have my password in some file, and don't want to put it in `.emacs` again.

Answer (score 6):

I believe there's no easy way to do what you want without involving buffers.  I'd use a temporary buffer like so:

```
(defun file-contents (filename)
  (interactive "fFind file: ")
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents filename)
    (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max))))
```

Though you may want to use `insert-file-contents-literally` if you don't want format decoding, auto uncompression, etc.